# jQuery UI sortable disabled not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently using this code for my sortable list

```
$("#playsortable").sortable({
  items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
}).disableSelection();
```

I'm dynamically adding items to the list and in certain instances I use the following code to disable the element.

```
$("#playsortable > li").first().addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

For some reason even if I to refresh the sortable list it can still be moved around. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried `"li:not('.ui-state-disabled')"?`. What errors do you see in the console? Also, a jsFiddle.net example might be helpful here.

Comment: After getting a jsfiddle setup for you I noticed that the code I used worked. I went back to my original code removed .sortable('refresh') and it started to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I managed to resolve the issue.

After setting up a jsfiddle and finding on that the code I used worked I went back to my own code and noticed that I was refreshing after inserting each new element

```
$("#playsortable").sortable('refresh');
```

After removing this code the sortable disable started to work.

For those who want to see the code you can find it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/v3C94/